# Compact metric spaces is second countable and axiom of countable choice

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice, second-countable

Why we need axiom of countable choice to prove following theorem:
every compact metric spaces is second countable?

In which step it's "hidden"?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The "obvious" proof uses countable choice, Why we *need* countable choice is a harder question.

Comment: @Andres, I'm knee deep in references...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually the proof would go like this:

For every $n$ define $\mathcal U_n=\{B(x,\frac1n)\mid x\in X\}$, this is clearly an open cover so it has a finite subcover $\mathcal V_n$.

Finally we can show that $\bigcup\mathcal V_n$ is a basis for the topology.

Here used twice countable choice:

1. We chose a finite subcover for every $n$.
2. We took the union of countably many finite sets, each with more than one element. Then we claim that this union is countable.

Both things are a consequence of the axiom of countable choice, and cannot be proved in general without it.

---

In the following paper the authors show that for compact metric spaces the statement that the space is separable is equivalent to the statement that it is second-countable. This makes it easier to find a counterexample, as non-separable compact metric spaces are easier to come by.

> Keremedis, Kyriakos; Tachtsis, Eleftherios. "**[Compact metric spaces and weak forms of the axiom of choice.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/1521-3870(200101)47:1%3C117::AID-MALQ117%3E3.0.CO%3B2-N)**" *MLQ Math. Log. Q.* **47** (2001), no. 1, 117–128.

Models where these fail (i.e. there is a compact metric space which is not second-countable) are also given.

Comment: Thank you! But in reason nr 2. if $ \ \mathcal V_n = \{B(x_{n,i},\frac{1}{n}), i=1,...,d(n)\} $ for some function $ d $ and if we take $ f_{n}:\mathcal V_n \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ such that $ f_{n}(B(x_{n,i}))=i$ we cannot use this functions (injections) to prove that $ \bigcup\mathcal V_n $ is countable? Is that because we have to know more about choosing $ x_{n,i} $ and $ d(n) $?

Comment: If you can uniformly enumerate the $\mathcal V_n$'s then you can indeed show that their union is countable. But generally I don't see any reason for that to be true. Think about $[0,1]$. How many real numbers can be chosen for a cover by intervals of length $\frac18$? Can you uniformly choose from these real numbers?

Comment: Why does the countability of a countable union of fine sets require (any form of) choice? Shouldn't this follow from the countability of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$? Does that also require choice?

Comment: @CarlosEsparza: Because you need to *choose* injections from the finite sets into $\Bbb N$. The proof that $\Bbb{N\times N}$ is countable does not require us to make infinitely many choices.