# Is every compact metric space hereditarily separable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. I see why all open and closed subsets of $X$  are separable. But is *every* subset of $X$ necessarily separable?

EDIT: Since $X$ is separable metric, it embeds into the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$, which is hereditarily separable, right? And so $X$ is also hereditarily separable.

Comment: If I recall correctly, every separable metric space is second countable. That should do it.

Comment: Countable Choice turns out to be necessary and sufficient. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/573787/28900) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864197001387).

Answer (score 2):

Yes: a compact metric space is second countable, and second countability is hereditary and implies separability.

Comment: Once upon a time, 3 seconds before...