# Compactness gives Second countable space??

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, second-countable

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space. If we know that $X$ is compact can we assume that is also second countable ??

Because X is compact we have that $X=\cup_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}$, where $V_{i}$ are open sets. So for every $U\subset X$ we have that $U\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}$. Can we assume that by choosing some of the $V_{i}$ we will have that $U=\cup_{i\in J}V_{i}$, $J$ is countable.

In order for $(X,\mathcal{T})$ to have a countable topology base ??

Comment: [No](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=~Second%20Countable%20%2B%20Compact).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573787/491874: for metric spaces it is true, assuming a weak form of the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Tychonoff's theorem, the arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact.
Take $X=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology and let $Y$ be the direct
product of an uncountable collection of copies of $X$. Then $Y$ is compact,
but $Y$ is not first countable (let alone second countable).

Comment: It is not true in general, but yes with metric spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is any set, the cofinite topology on $X$ is compact and any base for it has size $|X|$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\epsilon$-order  topology on the ordinal $\omega_1+1$  is compact Hausdorff but not 2nd-countable. It has an uncountable subset of isolated points: $\{x+1:x\in \omega_1\}\cup \{0\}.$

It is not even 1st-countable: The  *point*  $ \omega_1$ has uncountable character.