is $\frac{G}{N}$ second countable?
I'm trying to understand the proof of all compact topological groups are $\mathbb{R}-$factorizable, proof by Tkatchenko. I'm assuming all groups to be Tychonoff.
I defined the quotient group $\frac{G}{N}$ where $N$ is the coset containing the identity. I've already proved that $N$ is closed, hence $G/N$ is compact, Hausdorff. And I also proved that $\frac{G}{N}$ is metrizable. My only problem is to understand why $\frac{G}{N}$ is second countable. I need this to conclude that the group $G$ is $\mathbb{R}-$factorizable, maybe there's some equivalence I'm not seeing.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573787/compact-metric-spaces-is-second-countable-and-axiom-of-countable-choice
